# Prove $f(x+y)=f(x) + y' \nabla f(x) + \frac{1}{2} y' ( \int_0^1 ( \int_0^t \nabla^2 f(x+ \tau y) d \tau)dt)y$ when f twice differentiable over sphere

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

In the book http://www.athenasc.com/nonlinbook.html by Dimitri P. Bertsekas, there is a proposition A.23(a) in Appendix A without proof that :

[image]

I am able to prove the other two statements (b) and (c) which use Taylor series but unable to prove this one. How can this statement be proved?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem ?

Comment: @PNDas As I said, I am not really sure how to expand Taylor theorem to this case.